# How to sum the number from td tag using id with array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, input

I am trying to get a sum of numbers inside `td` tag and the tags have `id=total[]` which comes as an array. Example **:**

```
<td id="total[1]">200<td>
<td id="total[2]">400<td>
<td id="total[3]">500<td>
...etc
```

How do I get the sum of all of them using the id ?

Comment: `[...document.querySelectorAll('td')].reduce((sum, cell) => sum + parseInt(cell.textContent), 0)` the frequent use of `#id` will cripple your code.

Comment: Are you creating these `td` dynamically by using an array ? or these are static one ? As solution will be depend on how these td's are creating.

Comment: You are not closing td tags with /, it should be <td">.......</td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery example for your HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var Sum = 0;
    $("[id*=total]").each(function(){
          Sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });
  $("#ttl").text(Sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <td id="total[1]">200<td>
 <td id="total[2]">400<td>
 <td id="total[3]">500<td>
</table>
 Total: <span id="ttl"></span>
```

Comment: This works thank you, but what about if i want id="ttl" to be dramatic, when a value is changed on td or added, i want "ttl" to change without refreshing the page or clicking anything, similar to onchange is this was inside input field.

Comment: @lewin https://codepen.io/zz_coder/pen/eYMgQWM

Answer (score 0):

If there is no particular reason for you to use id, it is better to use class.

for example:

```
<td class="foo">200<td>
<td class="foo">400<td>
<td class="foo">500<td>
...etc
```

Then you can add the values by looping over the elements:

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
var sum = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    sum += parseFloat(items.item(i).innerHTML);
}
```